# Should I change my domain suffix for better SEO?

Tags: seo, domains, search-engines, ranking

In the start of 2013 my blog started to fail. I do not know whether its the result of a SEO problem or because I didn't write much. I received a lot of guest post requests and accepted many. They brought a lot of links which I think might have contributed to the problem. I removed many guest posts from the site. I stopped writing and only wrote a handful of posts for almost an year. Now I want to restart it.

I bought a new domain and moved the site to it. But is it a good move? How to find out whether my old one is bad?

My old domain : techhamlet.com
the new one : techhamlet.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future readers, I would like to say this. Unless you have been a really bad spammer, porn site, or something just plain horrible, there is no need to move your site to another domain to repair your placement in search engines. You are actually making the problem worse. You lose any of the positive metrics your domain name has amassed over the years at the very least.

Figure out what is dragging your site down or what you have not done to compete and fix it. In this case, the OP used guest posting which in of itself was not necessarily bad depending on how it was done, but also admits that the site lacked updating. Had he not moved his domain, I would have suggested checking inbound backlinks, any duplicate content, and begin posting immediately at least 2-3 per week and post in a focused planned way which I could have described. I would have also recommended building backlinks in simple, consistent, and slow ways/pace. I still recommend these things for his new domain name, however he now has to contend with 301 redirects from a domain he felt was a bad performer. In a sense, he just moved the problem.

In short, unless there is a huge problem like I described in the opening sentence and not just a performance problem, do not move your domain to try and fix search performance. If you want to move your domain, then that is another issue. Fix the problems first. You still have to do the work to fix the performance problems regardless.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I have gone to the new domain. Is it ok to back to the old one? Will it mess things up even more?

Comment: @EApubs If it were my site, I would go back and fix the .com version rather than dealing with 301 redirects for links and so forth. I would recommend researching why your old site has lost ground first. Generally, it is for simple reasons that can be fixed. One warning however, for each month your site lagged in performance is likely how long it will be to get it back. This is not a hard and fast rule, just a generalization. If it has been years, then it really won't take that long, but plan on a year before things begin to settle in and you perform as you should. It can go much quicker.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** It's a different domain, and even though your .com started failing, you can recover the old good SEO status.

Actually, you didn't need to ask this question:

[image]

The first result for a search for `techhamlet` is your .net site :)

Comment: Actually thats because .com is redirected to .net. If I change it back then .com will come to the top. Is it ok to change it back?

Comment: It's not that minefield-y. Google tries hard not to punish good intentions and allows graceful recovery from technical failures. Move your site back, just don't do that too often.